# SQL Server Database Getting NULL values

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm using a SQL Server database to store data for my project. I have some functions (c#) which use SQL queries to get null values.

My query goes perfect but I'm not able handle null value in my code.

```
public satic string getValue(int paramOne, string alternateString)
{
    var db = Database.Open("MyDatabase");
    var query = "SELECT * FROM UserData WHERE ColumnOne = @0 AND ColumnTwo = SomeValue";
    var row = db.QuerySingle(query, paramOne);
    var data = row.data;
    var returnValue = "";

    // Here comes the problem
    if(data == null)
    {
        returnValue = alternateString;
    }
    else
    {
        returnValue = data;
    }

    return returnValue;
}
```

When I execute this function, I get error

> Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: And `public satic` has to be `public static` I assume?

Comment: What data access component are you using for this (`Database.Open` and `db.QuerySingle`) or is it your own? If so we probably need to see the code for that, or what don't know what `row` actually is. Anyway, if data is a single value, you are probably looking for [`Convert.IsDBNull`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.isdbnull%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: @SonerGönül It looks strange, but it's a `WebMatrix.Database.Query` query string syntax.

Comment: @AndyKorneyev Oh, didn't know that. What is it for by the way? Is it for named parameters or parameter order etc.?

Comment: @SonerGönül It is for parameter order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you SQL query does not returns anything, then `row` (as result of `db.QuerySingle`) will be null.

So you have to check it before accessing `row.data` something like this:

```
var returnValue = "";

if(row != null && row.data != null)
    returnValue = row.data;
else
    returnValue = alternateString;
```